# Get last entry of a range with identical numbers in R, vectorized

Tags: r

I’ve got this data:

```
tribble(
    ~ranges, ~last,
    0,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    2,     NA,
    2,     NA,
    2,     NA,
    3,     NA,
    3,     NA
)
```

and I want to fill the `last` column only at the row index at the last entry of the number by the `ranges` column. That means, it should look like this:

```
tribble(
    ~ranges, ~last,
    0,     0,
    1,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    1,     NA,
    1,     1,
    2,     NA,
    2,     NA,
    2,     2,
    3,     NA,
    3,     3
)
```

So far I came up with a row-wise approach:

```
for (r in seq.int(max(tmp$ranges))) {
  print(r)
  range <- which(tmp$ranges == r) |> max()
  tmp$last[range] <- r
}
```

The main issue is that it is terribly slow. I am looking for a vectorized approach to this issue. Any creative solution out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
tmp %>%
  group_by(ranges) %>%
  mutate(
    last = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ ranges, TRUE ~ NA_real_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#    ranges  last
#     <dbl> <dbl>
#  1      0     0
#  2      1    NA
#  3      1    NA
#  4      1    NA
#  5      1     1
#  6      2    NA
#  7      2    NA
#  8      2     2
#  9      3    NA
# 10      3     3
```

Or we could do something clever with base R for the same result. Here we calculate the difference of `ranges` to identify when the next row is different (i.e., the last of a group). We then stick a `TRUE` on the end so the last row is included. This assumes your data is already sorted by `ranges`.

```
tmp$last = ifelse(c(diff(tmp$ranges) != 0, TRUE), tmp$ranges, NA)
```

Comment: For me, only `mutate(last = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ ranges))` works fine after grouping.

Comment: You're right! Looking at `?case_when` *"If no cases match, NA is returned."*. But it feels stylistically wrong to me to not spell it out...

Comment: I did simplify to `TRUE ~ NA_real_`, which lets me skip the `as.numeric()` line. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks all, the base R solution performs way faster with only 60ms execution time for over a million rows. The latest dplyr version of your solution takes about 7 seconds. I go for the base R. It is also somewhat more conscience.

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ranges) %>% 
  mutate(last = replace(last, n(), ranges[n()]))
```

---

Using `ifelse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ranges) %>% 
  mutate(last = ifelse(row_number() == n(), ranges, NA))
```

---

Using `tail`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ranges) %>% 
  mutate(last = c(last[-n()], tail(ranges, 1)))
```

output

```r
   ranges  last
    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      0     0
 2      1    NA
 3      1    NA
 4      1    NA
 5      1     1
 6      2    NA
 7      2    NA
 8      2     2
 9      3    NA
10      3     3
```